# In C# does (new Obj()).foo() dispose of Obj when the parenthesis scope is exited?

Tags: c#, scope, dispose

I am happy using `IDisposable` and `using` blocks but often I find myself writing `(new Obj()).Foo();` to avoid the extra instantiation code and naming etc. Does this instance hang in memory until the end of the function scope or is it disposed of directly after the enclosing parenthesis is exited...? Is there an alternative I am missing? An equivalent to implementing `IDisposable` for concrete objects that I want to use once and throw away?

Comment: Does Obj class implement IDisposable? You're talking disposed here, not garbage collected, right?

Comment: As is explained by numerous references, the reason for implementing `IDisposable` is to provide deterministic cleanup. If you don't call `IDisposable.Dispose()` explicitly, it doesn't happen deterministically, and you are at the mercy of the GC to eventually get around to calling the finalizer. See e.g. [Implementing a Dispose Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx)

Comment: And no, there is not any more concise way to do this than `using (Obj o = new Obj()) o.Foo();`

Comment: "until the end of the function scope" - are you sure you are not reading book about C++? Nothing specific happens to allocated objects when function ends in C#...

Comment: @hatchet I was talking about GC and when it is triggered. My laziness has me avoiding the extra using code.

Comment: @Peter So its left to the discretion of the GC that makes perfect sense the question is does the GC recognize that that instance has no pointer to it and suck it up immediately?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am indeed from a C++ background but I'd assumed (naively) that the end of the function scope would be a trigger for the GC... Am I wrong? Please enlighten me...

Comment: Function and block scope have nothing to do with GC. Objects referenced only by variables declared within a given scope may be collected prior to the end of the scope (if no longer used), or well after, or anywhere in between. Likewise, IDisposable has nothing to do with when the object itself is collected; it's just a language-supported idiom for adding explicit lifetime management to a managed object.

Comment: "How GC works" is a bit too broad for SO. Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx - it is a good starting point, especially if you have C++ background.

Answer (score 2):

IDisposable is not related whit when the memory allocated for the object is released. In both cases the memory is released when the Garbage Collector decides to release it.

IDisposable is used for objects that need to execute some action in order to release the resources it allocates outside them. For example if the objects open a Database connection, you must release it as soon as you don't need it anymore.

So IDisposable gives you one thing:

- A way to release the resources as soon as you want, by calling the Dispose() method or using the using clause

So it's ok to do:

```
new Obj()).Foo();
```

And has no sense to make Obj implements IDisposable if it does not uses any resource that must be deallocated.

Comment: If Obj implements IDisposable, it may not be ok to ignore disposing. If the resource is finite (and often they are), you could exhaust the resources before the objects get finalized. I've seen this happen with the email class in .Net. If IDisposable is implemented, the objects should be explicitly disposed.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. But in case that for some programming error the Dispose method is not invoked, at least when GC collect it, the resources are released. Thanks for the comment, I will edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: The GC will not automatically release unmanaged/scarce resources when it runs, unless the object has a finalizer (method with syntax similar to C++ destructor syntax). The GC doesn't look for `IDisposable`, it looks for finalizers. If there's a finalizer, it marks the object for finalization, and the next time it runs, it will call the finalizer. The finalizer should be calling `Dispose()`, although it's also possible to have a finalizer without `IDisposable`, which just means the consumer of your class cannot explicitly release resources (which is bad).

Comment: You are right, I thought you must override the Finalizer when implementing IDisposable, but after a little review it is not always the case. My opinion is that when you implement IDisposable you must override the finalizer, but is only my point of view

Comment: @PabloA.Revert: Finalizers can run in an arbitrary thread context, while some objects require cleanup that can only be performed in the thread that created them. Note that the purpose of `IDisposable` is not to allow an object to clean up *itself*, but rather to let it clean up *outside* entities that have been asked to do something on its behalf. Thread-safety may not seem relevant to the object being finalized (since presumably the reason it's being finalized is that no thread was using it), but it may be a problem for other entities that were acting on behalf of that object.

Comment: @supercat: you are right, I've edited the answer to only reflect the question about IDisposable, because Finalizers are a subject on its own. Thanks

Comment: Using `(new Obj()).Foo();` does  not ensure timely cleanup of a class that requires it. If the class implements `IDisposable`, it is imperative that you call the `Dispose()` method explicitly from your own code.

Answer (score 2):

If an object implements `IDisposable`, it is *imperative* that you `Dispose()` the object in your own code, either explicitly (and within a try/finally construct, too!) or with the `using` syntax, and do not simply let the reference(s) fall out of scope.

**EDIT: I feel like I used an awful lot of words to get around to explaining the most important aspect of all this, which is that the only reason an object should implement `IDisposable` is if it holds handles to other objects that are unmanaged (the CLR doesn't know about them) or scarce (due to resources/cost/licensing/etc.). So if an object implements `IDisposable`, you MUST call `Dispose()` YOURSELF, as soon as possible. The CLR will not do it for you. And if you implement `IDisposable` on your own classes, you need to be implementing a finalizer on them, too.**

Simply letting a reference fall out of scope does **not** cause the GC to run immediately, and you have no guarantees whatsoever that a GC is going to occur any time soon. You can explicitly trigger a GC with code, but that is typically going to hurt overall performance more than help it.

If there is not much memory pressure, for instance, the CLR may wait a long time before running the GC. There just isn't a pressing need for it to run in a situation where there is light or zero contention for resources. If it ran too often, it would impact the performance of your applications negatively

**The GC does not call `Dispose()`.** The GC calls an object's finalizer if it has one. The finalizer is a special method using syntax similar to a C++ destructor, but which really is not a destructor in that sense.

So if an object implements `IDisposable`, but does not implement a finalizer, the GC will never release that object's resources. The object will cause both memory leaks and unresolvable resource contention.

Nor does calling `Dispose()` from your own code trigger a GC.

The finalizer is a last-ditch backup mechanism to try to ensure that a class holding scarce or expensive resources does *eventually* let go of them even if consumers of the class fail to explicitly release those resources.

`IDisposable` is really just a common convention, implemented with a handy well-known interface contract, to let callers generically request that any class holding scarce resources release those resources immediately.

The standard pattern is that the finalizer calls the `Dispose()` method (actually, it typically calls `Dispose(false)` and I'm intentionally ignoring that detail). The `Dispose()` method will release all the scarce resources, then it can call `GC.SuppressFinalize()` so that the GC can free the object's memory more quickly when it gets around to running.

The old tried and true "acquire late/release early" semantics apply here.

You should read up on how the GC uses multiple passes or "generations" to clean up objects with finalizers.

The GC can get rid of regular objects (objects where all the resources are managed by the CLR) in one pass. If there are no in-scope references to an object, the GC can basically just delete it.

But if an object has a finalizer (and `GC.SuppressFinalize()` has not been called), the GC uses at least 2 passes or generations to release the object. In the first generation, it marks the object for finalization. In the second generation (which happens the next time the GC runs), it actually calls the finalizer, and at that point the object is finally eligible to have its memory released.

The scarce/expensive resources we're talking about are typically things like network sockets, file handles, database or other server connections which may be limited or expensive or resource-intensive or all three, etc. This is also true of virtually all "unmanaged" (non .NET CLR) resources, including things like Win32 window handles, file handles, network sockets and so on.  Such resources require deterministic cleanup. You need to let go of them as quick as you can, but the CLR is going to take its sweet time getting around to cleaning this stuff up. You have to do it yourself.

But if your class isn't using any of these types of scarce/expensive/"unmanaged" resources, then there is probably no reason to implement `IDisposable` on it at all.